# Cylindrical Archway Topology

Tags: modeling, rendering, topology

So I'm modelling a castle tower and am putting archways in it. I'm trying to make this one mesh (so I don't want to make the archway separate and make a hole in the mesh, I want to extrude the outline) but modelling with correct topology is proving to be a challenge.
[image]

I can't find another way to make the topology look cleaner without ngons (the bottom rectangles seem to be best left as ngons since the vertices are all parallel on a straight line).

[image]

This creates a few lighting artifacts as shown here ^.

[image]

But in the material preview mode ^ I don't see anything wrong. So the question is, is the current topology sufficient? Do I need to change anything if I don't see anything wrong in the render, especially if I add textures? Or is there some way I can improve this.

Comment: Are you intending to stay lo-poly. or is this for subdivision?

Comment: I want this to stay low-poly